AWS SAM Lambda - Google Drive service account issue
I have been using an AWS SAM Lambda for 6x months now to trigger a file create method to a Company Google Drive shared folder with the service account. As of Friday the 27th of Sept 2024 this create method started failing with the CloudWatch log error -
"Recieved error: Too Many Requests b'<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/><title>Sorry...</title><style> body { font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; color: #000; }</style></head><body><div><table><tr><td><b><font face=sans-serif size=10><font color=#4285f4>G</font><font color=#ea4335>o</font><font color=#fbbc05>o</font><font color=#4285f4>g</font><font color=#34a853>l</font><font color=#ea4335>e</font></font></b></td><td style=\"text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 50%\"><div style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;\">Sorry...</div></td></tr></table></div><div style=\"margin-left: 4em;\"><h1>We\\'re sorry...</h1><p>... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can\\'t process your request right now.</p></div><div style=\"margin-left: 4em;\">See <a href=\"https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640\">Google Help</a> for more information.<br/><br/></div><div style=\"text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;\"><a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Google Home</a></div></body></html>'"

The trigger only fires 10 - 20 times a day but sometimes 5 request do come through at once.
The Folder create methods still work fine, and also backing up to Google Storage works fine.
self.credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(credentials_path,scopes=scopes)
file_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=self.credentials)
file = file_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media_body, fields='id').execute()

Currently have switched to using OAuth 2.0 Client setup with refresh token, but the setup to run in AWS SAM Lambda is painful and brings it's own issues.
self.credentials = Credentials(
     token=self.tokens['access_token'],
     refresh_token=self.tokens['refresh_token'],
     token_uri='https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
     client_id='************************.apps.googleusercontent.com',
     client_secret=os.environ.get("DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET"),
     scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"]
     )
self.refresh_drive_credentials_if_needed()

I've also implemented exponential backoff and time delays if a fail occurs but still no good.
Runs Local debug fine without errors.
If anyone has had the same issues would be good to hear your experiences.

I checked Google’s Public Issue Tracker at issuetracker.google.com and found a current issue where instances are hitting limits without actually exceeding them. For more details, you can visit this link: related ongoing cases
